# Django app failing in Travis CI: server not running on localhost

Tags: django, postgresql, travis-ci

I am testing a sample Django app in Travis CI using a Postgres database. I wrote some basic tests for models that passed successfully on my development environment. When I push the code to Travis the following error occurs:

travis link : https://travis-ci.org/Navajyoth/django-travis/jobs/64052563

github link : https://github.com/Navajyoth/django-travis

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 210, in run_tests
old_config = self.setup_databases()
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
**kwargs
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 354, in create_test_db
self._create_test_db(verbosity, autoclobber, keepdb)
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 447, in _create_test_db
with self._nodb_connection.cursor() as cursor:
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 164, in cursor
cursor = self.make_cursor(self._cursor())
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
self.ensure_connection()
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 172, in get_new_connection
connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused

Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

The command "python manage.py test apps.account --settings=settings.dev" exited with 1.

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The build is failing because you are using postgres as a db backend to test your app. The traceback shows `psycopg2` is unable to connect on localhost:

```
File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect 
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory,async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server:Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused`
```

You should either use sqlite as a db backend or specify correct database connection 
parameters in your `settings.dev`. refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Comment: In my machine psycopg2 doesn't show any error or warning and successfully passed the tests.Only in Travis CI shows this error.

Comment: Its because you have a postgresql server installed in your local machine whereas travis creates a different virtual machine everytime you initiate a build on which there's no postgres server installed.

Comment: @NavajyothMS: Did you read travis documentation on using postgresql? The answer to your question is in it. On the top of the first page, with title "Using PostgreSQL in your Builds"…

Comment: @spectras:Thanks for your advise.Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Main issues in the above problem.

(1) Unsupported  version of PostgreSQL
(2) Removing patch release version from PostgreSQL addon.

It fixed the problem